# Calculate conditional total

Tags: google-sheets, google

I would like to compute for the total unpaid (status is a checkbox,true/false) for any specific person.

```
Name     Amount   Paid   
Me       100      ✓
You      20       (unchecked/False)
Me       50       (unchecked/False)
Me       30       (unchecked/False)
You      20       ✓
```

The result would be Me=80

Comment: Would a pivot table not work for this analysis?

Answer (score 0):

`=sumifs(B2:B6,A2:A6,B8,C2:C6,false)`

---

[sumifs](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3238496) - Returns the sum of a range depending on multiple criteria.

In this case, criteria#1 is the name, and criteria#2 is the status of unpaid (or FALSE)

---

[image: Screenshot]